# How to extract a string between special character on a column dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this Python Pandas DataFrame:

```
Municipio
São Caetano do Sul (SP)
Florianópolis (SC)
Vitória (ES)
```

How to extract the term between () and turn it into:

```
Municipio                   UF
São Caetano do Sul (SP)     (SP)
Florianópolis (SC)          (SC)
Vitória (ES)                (ES)
```

Comment: The first row doesn't have any value inside `()`, so it should return `UF` for such rows?

Comment: @IshanShishodiya I suspect that the first row contains the column headers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```py
df['UF'] = df['Municipio'].str.extract('(\([^)]*\))')
```

```
print(df)

                 Municipio  UF
0  São Caetano do Sul (SP)  (SP)
1       Florianópolis (SC)  (SC)
2             Vitória (ES)  (ES)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['UF'] = df['Municipio'].str.split('(').str[1].str[:-1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.extract` we can try:

```py
df["UF"] = df["Municipio"].str.extract(r'(\([A-Z]+\))')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a named capturing group:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Municipio": [
                "São Caetano do Sul (SP)",
                "Florianópolis (SC)",
                "Vitória (ES)",
            ]
        }
    )
    print(f"df=\n{df}")
    df = df["Municipio"].str.extract(r"(?P<Municipio>.+(?=\())(?P<UF>\(\w+\))")
    print(f"df_extracted=\n{df}")
```

outputs:

```
df=
                 Municipio
0  São Caetano do Sul (SP)
1       Florianópolis (SC)
2             Vitória (ES)
df_extracted=
             Municipio    UF
0  São Caetano do Sul   (SP)
1       Florianópolis   (SC)
2             Vitória   (ES)
```